# How to take a white product on a white background?

Tags: product-photography, background

I can't get a decent white background on my product shots

Here are few samples

[image]

[image]

After editing in Photoshop
[image: using photoshop]

Comment: You have all sorts of problems going on there, the fact that the product is white is the least of them. The thing to remember with this is that the product is not actually perfect white so it will show against a white background if done properly but it is obviously not going to out as much as if it were say; on a black background.

Answer (score 1):

The diffused light source is a big problem. Harder edge lights will help create some edges on the bottle and separate it from the background. If you replaced the soft plastic bottle with a glass bottle, you would see the specular highlights that would help define it. With a soft plastic bottle on a soft white background lit with soft diffused light, you are fighting an uphill battle.